# Add to home screen functionality using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want "add to home screen" functionality on button click using `javascript`. My first question is. Is that possible using `javascript` or `html/css`?

I have read too many post but did not find any working code. what I found is  user have to do is to go to chrome menu and tab on "add to home screen" or chrome will prompt the user and ask them "add to home screen"

Comment: Unfortunately, seems they've kneecapped PWAs. There's no button that shows up; they have to add it themselves. And if your site requires logging in, guess what, iOS home screen links have separate cookies, so the user is logged out.

Answer (score 27):

Image below shows the project structure in file explorer. A public folder has all the file is inside it. And the manifest file is outside the public folder [image: this is the image]

Next create Manifest.json and service-worker.js files as shown below:

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "short_name": "BetaPage",
  "name": "BetaPage",
  "theme_color": "#4A90E2",
  "background_color": "#F7F8F9",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [
      {  
   "src": "assets/layouts/layout2/img/icon/android-icon-36x36.png",
   "sizes": "36x36",
   "type": "image/png",
   "density": "0.75"
  },
    {
      "src": "assets/layouts/layout2/img/icon/android-icon-48x48.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
       "src": "assets/layouts/layout2/img/icon/android-icon-72x72.png",
   "sizes": "72x72",
   "type": "image/png",
   "density": "1.5"
  },

    {
    "src": "assets/layouts/layout2/img/icon/android-icon-96x96.png",
   "sizes": "96x96",
   "type": "image/png",
   "density": "2.0"
  },
  {
   "src": "assets/layouts/layout2/img/icon/android-icon-144x144.png",
   "sizes": "144x144",
   "type": "image/png",
   "density": "3.0"
  },
  {
   "src": "assets/layouts/layout2/img/icon/android-icon-192x192.png",
   "sizes": "192x192",
   "type": "image/png",
   "density": "4.0"
  }
  ],
  "start_url": "/index.html"
}
```

**service-worker.js**

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event){

});
```

Now edit **index.html** and add following code in **head section**

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">     
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

In the same file put below code right before **body** closing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log("Will the service worker register?");
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
      .then(function(reg){
        console.log("Yes, it did.");
     }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("No it didn't. This happened:", err)
    });
 }
</script>
```

Now Run your project, wait for few minute and reload your page.

ENJOY !

Comment: Thanks for the details.

Comment: I follow all the step, first 2/3 time it show me (popup), but after that it now showing any more.

Comment: When you say put all files inside the Public folder, do you mean to put all your application files inside Public folders as if it were the root? @Rishi

Comment: If you put your file in root folder please include file with correct path, will work fine .@user2060451

Comment: I gave up on this so long ago after trying so many solutions which all flopped, tried this today and voila like magic it works instantly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rishi! Adding this empty "service worker" was very useful, and allowed the *"Add to Home screen"* to show automatically on Chrome for Android :) Documentation: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners

Comment: @Basj  Pleasure mine sir

Comment: Unbelievable. I install 3 React libs and read 2 longwinded Medium articles, no avail. Then this answer just makes it work. Thanks!

Comment: Yes as the comments as in 2022 it still works great on chrome.. though only chrome and not on other browsers. is there cross platform solution?

Comment: Doesn't work in Safari iOS

Answer (score 10):

In June 2018, Google introduce Chrome 68 (still in Beta at July 2018) that allow you show a modal add to home screen dialog by catching event "`beforeinstallprompt`".

To trigger this event, you need:

- The web app is not already installed
- Meets a user engagement heuristic (currently, the user has interacted with the domain for at least 30 seconds)
- Web app manifest must have: `short_name` or `name`, `icon`, `start_url`, and `display`
- Must be https
- Has registered a service worker with a "`fetch`" event handler

More detail and code at: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/a2hs-updates

Add to home screen criteria: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#criteria

Answer (score 3):

According to the **Best Practices** section of this page: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen#best-practices

- Do not prompt the user to add your app to the homescreen. There is no way to detect if the app is running installed or not.

---

It looks like other developers have suggested that you can simply prompt the user with instructions for how to add to the homescreen, rather than try and do it directly.

---

EDIT: Doing more digging, it seems that since chrome 42, google is introducing app install banners. See: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android

Your web app will need to meet a bunch of requirements however, including running a [service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-worker/), having your site as https, and having the user visit your site at least twice.

Comment: I dont wana promt them. I just want to show Icon. on clicking on that Icon user can page to home screen

Comment: I understand that, but as you can see by the link from the chrome team, you are not able to. Prompting them how is the closest option.

Comment: There does seem to be a way of accomplishing this, which I have linked.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2022:

**Includes a web app manifest that includes:**

- `short_name` or name
- `icons` - must include a **192px** and a **512px** icon
- `start_url`
- `display` - must be one of `fullscreen`, `standalone`, or `minimal-ui`
- `prefer_related_applications` must not be present, or be `false`